# How to make a sidenav below the toolbar in vue material?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-material

So I am using vuejs with [vue-material](https://vuematerial.github.io) and I have a problem.

So this is what it looks like without the fixed sidenav.

[image]

And when I add a sidenav..

[image]

As you can see the toolbar is under the navbar which is not what I want to do. I want the sidenav under the toolbar.

My current code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <md-toolbar class="z-index:9999;">
      <md-button class="md-icon-button">
        <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <h2 class="md-title" style="flex: 1">Personal Data Sheet</h2>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button">
        <md-icon>search</md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-sidenav class="md-fixed" ref="leftSidenav">
      <md-toolbar class="md-large md-accent">
        <div class="md-toolbar-container">
        <md-avatar class="md-large">
          <img src="static/dost-seal.jpg" alt="People">
        </md-avatar>
          <h3 class="md-title">DOST - MIRDC</h3>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
    </md-sidenav>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try adding style to md-sidenav "top:64px", as side-nav has position fixed. This should do the trick!